# How to sort list items based on multiple attributes, while the last priority is alphabet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects, and I want to sort them based on multiple attributes. The list contains several teams (from class Team):

```
    teams = sorted([Spain,Portugal,Iran,Morocco], key= lambda x:(x.points,x.wins))
```

but I don't know how to put alphabetical order as the third sorting priority.

```
teams = sorted([Spain,Portugal,Iran,Morocco], key=lambda x: (x.points,x.wins))
for team in reversed(teams):
    print("%s  wins:%i , loses:%i , draws:%i , goal difference:%i , points:%i" %(team.name,team.wins,team.loses,team.draws,team.goal_difference,team.points))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the name as the last element of the tuple:

```
teams = sorted([Spain, Portugal, Iran, Morocco], key = lambda x : (x.points, x.wins, x.name))
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can I define that for the first two items the reverse = False, but for the last key (name) reverse = True?

Comment: @SafaGharavi You can sort twice, like this: `teams = sorted(sorted([Spain, Portugal, Iran, Morocco], key = lambda x : (x.points, x.wins)), key = lambda x : x.name, reverse = True)`.